# Interpolating noisy data

Tags: interpolation, data, filtering, smoothing

My data looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/n59CTB3L

Or if displayed in log chart:

[image: data in log chart]

I want to create an interpolation of the data that would remove most of the noise.

What are some good ways to plot a smooth curve through this data?

Comment: Perhaps  the underlying physical problem gives you an idea about the expected approximation.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146688/interpolate-the-noisy-data?rq=1)

Comment: Could smooth it first using any number of methods.One is just to average over a reasonable size set of neighbors e.g. `ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, 23]/23, plota1[[All, 2]]]`.

Comment: [Savitzky-Golay Filter to smooth noisy data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37380/280).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Quantile regression might produce results you want -- you have to experiment with the number of knots or the knots locations.

Get data:

```
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/n59CTB3L"];    
data = plota1;    
Dimensions[data]
```

Get the package [QuantileRegression.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/QuantileRegression.m):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
```

Quantile regression application:

```
knots = 400;

qFunc = First@
   QuantileRegression[data, knots, {0.5}, 
    Method -> {LinearProgramming, Tolerance -> 10^(-7)}];
```

Plot data and regression quantile in Log-Log scales:

```
Show[{
  ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]], 
  ListLogLogPlot[{#, qFunc[#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]], Joined -> True]},
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"QuantileRegression with ", knots, " knots"}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is awesome, thank you!

Comment: is there any way to make it find the required number of knots automatically?

Comment: Hm... that is in my TODO list for that package. It is not a simple question, several heuristics can be applied that work well in relatively narrow cases.

Comment: Another question. Is there any way I can give different points different weights?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but maybe adding multiple copies of the points you want to have more of an impact can produce results you want.

Comment: For example, I have different measurement precision for different x values, and I could specify that the points where measurement error is higher have lower weight. If I have to add points to give them more weight, I'm limited to integer numbers, while ideally that would be real numbers. Mathematica has this option to add weights for linear regression at least https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Weights.html

Comment: Well, you can use the functions found by `QuantileRegression` with `LinearModelFit` and specified weights.

Comment: I am trying to use your package on my data. However, it does something strange at the start and end of the data (produces vertical lines). Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: I think I know the answer: I have too many knots.

Comment: @Hugh If you find a way to share your data I will look into the issues ...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Is there any way to put error bars on your quantiles? I would expect the 0.5 quantile to have a small error bar and the 0.05 and 0.05 quantiles to have larger error bars. However, can error bars be added?

Comment: @Hugh I am not sure what do you mean by error bars -- there are at least two interpretations. The more interesting for Quantile Regression is to verify how good the fits of "my quantiles" are by finding the fractions of the data points below or above the regression quantiles. If you want a more detailed answer, please post a MSE question.

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the data I would expect a constant value for increasing x-values.
So the approximation could be something with Exp[-...t],for example

```
NonlinearModelFit[plota1,a0 - a1 Exp[-\[Alpha]1 t] - a2  t Exp[-\[Alpha]2 t] , {a0, a1,a2 , \[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2 }, t] 
Show[{ListPlot[plota1],Plot[Normal[%], {t, Min[plota1[[All, 1]]], Max[plota1[[All,1]]]},PlotRange -> All]}]
```

gives this result
[image: approx]

Comment: good solution. But in log, the curve falls too slowly, and than rises too slowly (you can see that it misses a cluster of points near 50, and than another huge chunk at around 500)

Comment: @ Arsen Zahray: Are you looking for a final approximation in Log-space? Please give some information concerning the related problem.

Comment: yes, I'm looking at the data in the log scale. as you can see on the chart, there is some activity in the beginning, than it subsides and for the most part of the observation, nothing really is happening