# Smoothing random data with MovingAverage

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, smoothing

If I have this kind of data:

```
SeedRandom[2912018];
x = RandomReal[{0, 5}, 100];
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

How can I apply `MovingAverage` to continously smooth the `y` data along `x` with an interval width of `dx = 0.5`? The variation step of `dx` should be `0.1`.

The `x intervals` would be:

```
[0.0, 0.5]
[0.1, 0.6]
[0.2, 0.7]
...
[4.3, 4.8]
[4.4, 4.9]
[4.5, 5.0]
```

So for the first `x` interval `[0.0, 0.5]` the average of all `y` values (=`yaverage1`) in this range would result into the point `{(0.0 + 0.5)/2, yaverage1}` etc. The last `x` value of the averaged data would be at `(4.5 +5.0)/2`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov 's quantile regression package (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162118/interpolating-noisy-data/162145#162145) will probably do what you want (and have an appropriate statistical basis for making inferences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure `MovingAverage` is the best choice here. It doesn't divide the data into bins, it just uses runs of consecutive elements. If you want to construct bins, it may be easiest to do it manually. For readability, I define it as a helper function using `Select`:

```
bin[xmin_, xmax_, l_] := Select[l, #[[1]] >= xmin && #[[1]] <= xmax &];
```

Then working with the data:

```
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
smoothdata = 
  Table[{xmin + 0.25, 
    Mean[Last /@ bin[xmin, xmin + 0.5, data]]}, {xmin, 0., 4.5, 0.1}];
```

This generates a smoothed data set as intended:

```
ListPlot[{data, smoothdata}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

> [image: Smoothed data vs. original data plot.]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this (that does not use `MovingMap` directly, this is just an alternative) is to use an `EventSeries` and `TimeSeriesAggregate`.

```
ListPlot[{Transpose@{x, y}, 
  TimeSeriesAggregate[EventSeries[Transpose[{x, y}]], 0.5]}, 
 Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image: moving map]

Vary the `0.5` above to the time interval you would like (for instance 0.3).

You can use `Normal` on the resulting object from `TimeSeriesAggregate[EventSeries[Transpose[{x, y}]], 0.5]` to get the raw values.

However, I'm sure there's a way to do this with `MovingMap`, this is just a quick alternative I thought of.

Comment: Thank you. In the documentation of `TimeSeriesAggregate` is written: "`TimeSeriesAggregate[tseries,dt]` computes the mean value of `tseries` over non-overlapping windows of width `dt`." >>>  I would like that the intervall `dt` moves in small steps through the whole `x` range. I think this would produce another averaged curve, what do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got a clue :) I don't know anything useful about maths, I just see WL functions and use them and hope they're right!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use for a BinListBy function, but Mathematica does not have one. Let's write our own:

```
binListsBy[data_, f_, opts___] := Module[{binBy, binning, select},
  (*function f must return a list acceptable to BinLists*)
  binBy = f /@ data;
  (*construct bins of binBy values*)
  binning = Union /@ BinLists[binBy, opts];
  (*selects data elements for which f[element] is in a list*)
  select[l_] := Select[data, MemberQ[l, f[#]] &];
  (*use select to bin the original data according to the binning \
lists*)
  select /@ binning
  ]
```

Create and bin the data:

```
data = {RandomReal[{0, 5}, 100], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]} // 
   Transpose;
(* bin the data by the x values *)
binnedData = binListsBy[data, #[[1]] &, .5];
```

Plot it:

```
ListPlot@data
```

[image]

```
(* take the mean of both x an y values in each bin *)
meanData = Mean /@ binnedData;
(* The means of the bins in both x and y *)
ListPlot[meanData, AxesLabel -> {"Mean X", "Mean Y"}]
```

[image]

```
(* the mean y values against bin numbers *)
ListPlot[meanData[[All, 2]], DataRange -> {0, 4.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Lower bin limit", "Mean Y"}]
```

[image]