# Factor to measure polynomial fit

Tags: interpolation, polynomials

I am trying to use `InterpolatingPolynomial` to fit a polynomial to a given set of points representing a relationship between two variables. I would like to find a measure between `0` and `1` of how much the polynomial represents the points, `1` being a perfect fit. Consequently, the measure will reflect a polynomial relationship between the two points. I am not sure how to extract this measure from the polynomial. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `InterpolatingPolynomial` will, if possible, find the (likely minimal) polynomial which exactly passes through the provided points. Thus, I'm not sure I understand your question. If you were fitting with a fixed length polynomial (e.g. using `LinearModelFit`), then you could use values such as `RSquared` or `AdjustedRSquared` for this purpose readily enough.

Comment: The Properties & Relations section of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) says _The interpolating polynomial always goes through the data points_.

Comment: @eyorble I am trying to establish a measure of a nonlinear relationship between two variables, something like the covariance but nonlinear, if this makes any sense..

Comment: But if the polynomial is guaranteed to perfectly match the points, how are we to estimate the error? As I understand it, all of the degrees of freedom from the data are already used to constrain the polynomial, and none remain to check the validity of the solution. Thus, I don't think such a measure can even exist with the interpolating polynomial.

Comment: The points form a cloud with many equally spaced so the polynomial will not fit them perfectly, I am looking for an optimal fit with a polynomial, so I am not sure if `InterpolatingPolynomial` is the best choice though.

Comment: `InterpolatingPolynomial` will add terms until the points are perfectly fit though, since unless two points share the same input value that is always possible. However, it sounds like you want a slightly more constrained polynomial model, and for that I'd recommend `LinearModelFit` once again, which already has many goodness-of-fit parameters readily calculable in its model object.

Answer (score 1):

While polynomial models fit in *Mathematica* can be relatively easy to transfer to other languages, you might want to consider a more modern method such as @AntonAntonov 's
[Quantile Regression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162118/interpolating-noisy-data/162145#162145) package.  (It would be very nice if *Mathematica* offered additional nonparametric regression functions such as generalized additive models.)

If you really have to have a polynomial with just enough terms to obtain a desired fit, you should consider something like the following approach:

1. Set some value for a desired root mean square error.  This is the standard deviation for a single observation.
2. Try multiple models where you calculate `AICc` for each polynomial model.  (If the output of `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` is `nlm`, then you get `AICc` with `nlm["AICc"]`.)
3. Choose the model with the smallest `AICc`.
4. If the best model has a root mean square error smaller than what you set for the desired root mean square error, then you're done.

The above model selection process is not the best or most consistent way to go. So asking this question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is recommended then implementing that advice in *Mathematica*.