# Fitting two peaks at the same time with NonLinearFit

Tags: fitting

If I have the following data:

`data={{68.029,0.0570654},{68.062,0.0571538},{68.095,0.0573135},{68.128,0.0573148},{68.161,0.0574761},{68.194,0.0576357},{68.227,0.0577004},{68.261,0.0574547},{68.293,0.0576841},{68.326,0.0576759},{68.359,0.0576677},{68.392,0.0577419},{68.426,0.0576339},{68.459,0.0577603},{68.492,0.0578867},{68.525,0.0580131},{68.558,0.0581791},{68.591,0.058209},{68.624,0.0583987},{68.657,0.0585884},{68.69,0.0587781},{68.723,0.0589489},{68.756,0.0589455},{68.788,0.0593332},{68.821,0.0594897},{68.855,0.0594118},{68.888,0.0597297},{68.921,0.0598878},{68.954,0.0600459},{68.987,0.0602039},{69.02,0.060362},{69.053,0.0605185},{69.086,0.0608349},{69.119,0.0609898},{69.152,0.0611463},{69.185,0.0613012},{69.218,0.0616191},{69.252,0.0615444},{69.285,0.0618623},{69.318,0.0620204},{69.351,0.0621785},{69.384,0.06246},{69.417,0.0625516},{69.45,0.0626448},{69.484,0.0625004},{69.517,0.0625919},{69.551,0.0625077},{69.584,0.0628557},{69.617,0.0630423},{69.65,0.0632304},{69.683,0.0634186},{69.716,0.0636083},{69.749,0.063798},{69.781,0.064219},{69.815,0.0641775},{69.848,0.0643672},{69.881,0.0647169},{69.914,0.0649034},{69.947,0.0650916},{69.981,0.0650469},{70.014,0.0652351},{70.048,0.065412},{70.08,0.0659248},{70.113,0.0662079},{70.146,0.0666526},{70.179,0.0669357},{70.211,0.0675735},{70.245,0.0677236},{70.278,0.0681065},{70.311,0.0683279},{70.345,0.0684795},{70.378,0.0689399},{70.41,0.0694242},{70.443,0.0696725},{70.476,0.0700807},{70.509,0.0703306},{70.542,0.0706581},{70.576,0.0709664},{70.609,0.0713477},{70.641,0.072117},{70.674,0.0724967},{70.707,0.0729983},{70.74,0.0733147},{70.773,0.0737894},{70.807,0.0738729},{70.84,0.0743492},{70.873,0.0748017},{70.905,0.0754776},{70.938,0.0759174},{70.971,0.0763589},{71.004,0.0768003},{71.037,0.0770851},{71.071,0.0772968},{71.104,0.077743},{71.136,0.0784236},{71.17,0.0787969},{71.202,0.0794364},{71.235,0.0798161},{71.268,0.0801958},{71.301,0.0807354},{71.335,0.0808791},{71.368,0.0813759},{71.401,0.081849},{71.434,0.0823206},{71.467,0.0827937},{71.5,0.0832652},{71.533,0.0837842},{71.566,0.084327},{71.6,0.0847952},{71.632,0.085574},{71.665,0.0862767},{71.698,0.0869382},{71.731,0.0874176},{71.764,0.0880569},{71.797,0.0885364},{71.831,0.0889381},{71.864,0.0895316},{71.897,0.0900997},{71.93,0.0906677},{71.962,0.0916349},{71.995,0.092203},{72.028,0.0929959},{72.061,0.0936669},{72.094,0.0944994},{72.128,0.0950927},{72.161,0.0959236},{72.194,0.0967117},{72.226,0.0977153},{72.259,0.0984781},{72.292,0.0992425},{72.326,0.0997677},{72.359,0.100592},{72.392,0.101612},{72.424,0.102709},{72.458,0.103492},{72.491,0.104351},{72.524,0.105329},{72.557,0.106281},{72.59,0.107233},{72.623,0.108186},{72.656,0.109137},{72.688,0.110454},{72.722,0.111212},{72.754,0.112434},{72.787,0.113425},{72.821,0.114023},{72.854,0.115609},{72.887,0.11701},{72.919,0.118166},{72.952,0.119087},{72.985,0.120647},{73.019,0.121519},{73.052,0.122638},{73.085,0.124236},{73.118,0.125355},{73.152,0.126241},{73.184,0.12771},{73.217,0.128761},{73.249,0.130048},{73.282,0.1311},{73.315,0.132311},{73.348,0.133561},{73.382,0.134444},{73.415,0.136361},{73.448,0.138117},{73.481,0.139392},{73.514,0.14127},{73.547,0.142484},{73.58,0.143859},{73.613,0.145075},{73.647,0.146214},{73.679,0.147801},{73.712,0.149138},{73.745,0.150314},{73.778,0.151652},{73.811,0.153147},{73.844,0.154569},{73.878,0.155968},{73.911,0.157598},{73.944,0.160028},{73.977,0.161818},{74.01,0.163267},{74.042,0.165097},{74.075,0.166852},{74.109,0.168215},{74.142,0.16981},{74.176,0.171334},{74.209,0.17341},{74.241,0.175559},{74.274,0.178596},{74.307,0.180671},{74.34,0.183791},{74.373,0.185997},{74.407,0.188137},{74.44,0.191785},{74.473,0.194151},{74.506,0.19644},{74.539,0.198997},{74.572,0.201552},{74.605,0.204268},{74.638,0.208585},{74.671,0.21142},{74.705,0.214154},{74.738,0.217443},{74.771,0.220733},{74.804,0.225942},{74.837,0.229501},{74.87,0.233596},{74.904,0.239381},{74.937,0.243794},{74.97,0.250129},{75.003,0.254638},{75.036,0.259594},{75.069,0.266791},{75.102,0.272708},{75.135,0.280225},{75.168,0.286304},{75.201,0.294463},{75.233,0.301094},{75.266,0.309735},{75.3,0.316702},{75.333,0.324539},{75.366,0.332695},{75.4,0.3427},{75.433,0.352938},{75.466,0.363334},{75.499,0.373573},{75.531,0.383886},{75.564,0.392686},{75.597,0.400206},{75.63,0.405805},{75.663,0.414404},{75.697,0.423062},{75.73,0.432275},{75.762,0.441723},{75.795,0.450937},{75.828,0.460329},{75.861,0.469574},{75.894,0.478018},{75.927,0.485343},{75.961,0.491474},{75.994,0.495995},{76.027,0.497268},{76.06,0.490378},{76.093,0.48685},{76.125,0.474117},{76.159,0.465758},{76.192,0.454619},{76.225,0.432919},{76.258,0.414738},{76.291,0.391278},{76.324,0.368156},{76.357,0.344888},{76.39,0.323379},{76.423,0.303791},{76.456,0.286443},{76.489,0.271034},{76.522,0.250037},{76.556,0.229126},{76.589,0.209889},{76.622,0.191613},{76.655,0.175856},{76.689,0.166238},{76.722,0.153977},{76.755,0.146995},{76.788,0.141294},{76.821,0.132634},{76.853,0.128412},{76.886,0.12476},{76.919,0.121907},{76.952,0.118894},{76.985,0.11618},{77.018,0.113294},{77.051,0.110726},{77.084,0.105919},{77.117,0.103671},{77.151,0.101397},{77.184,0.100018},{77.217,0.0965602},{77.25,0.0955008},{77.284,0.0943717},{77.316,0.0920634},{77.349,0.0911022},{77.382,0.0904608},{77.415,0.0899777},{77.448,0.0891764},{77.481,0.0883735},{77.515,0.0873346},{77.548,0.0866917},{77.581,0.0857257},{77.614,0.0846015},{77.647,0.0837004},{77.68,0.0826759},{77.713,0.0818113},{77.746,0.0811066},{77.779,0.0804018},{77.812,0.0797161},{77.845,0.079043},{77.878,0.0782101},{77.911,0.077537},{77.944,0.0770238},{77.977,0.0758204},{78.01,0.0752075},{78.043,0.0747545},{78.076,0.0741432},{78.109,0.0733704},{78.142,0.0727923},{78.176,0.0720162},{78.209,0.0716297},{78.243,0.0706922},{78.276,0.0701458},{78.309,0.0690658},{78.342,0.068741},{78.374,0.0680095},{78.407,0.0675264},{78.44,0.0670417},{78.473,0.0665729},{78.506,0.0661215},{78.539,0.0653487},{78.572,0.0650555},{78.605,0.064764},{78.638,0.0644709},{78.67,0.0645705},{78.703,0.0641191},{78.737,0.0635947},{78.77,0.0634615},{78.803,0.0629942},{78.836,0.0623528},{78.868,0.0621041},{78.901,0.061621},{78.934,0.0611395},{78.967,0.0607878},{79.001,0.0600038},{79.034,0.0596157},{79.067,0.0592276},{79.1,0.0588395},{79.133,0.0585448},{79.167,0.0581218},{79.199,0.0581549},{79.232,0.0579615},{79.265,0.0577665},{79.298,0.0577172},{79.331,0.0574874},{79.364,0.0572592},{79.397,0.057031},{79.43,0.0569627},{79.463,0.0566902},{79.497,0.0561294},{79.529,0.0560358},{79.562,0.0557095},{79.595,0.055543},{79.628,0.0552483},{79.66,0.0552181},{79.694,0.0548869},{79.727,0.054627},{79.76,0.054527},{79.794,0.0539853},{79.827,0.0537887},{79.86,0.0535922},{79.893,0.0532357},{79.926,0.0530408},{79.959,0.0526669},{79.993,0.0522043},{80.026,0.0519761},{80.06,0.0515119},{80.093,0.0514436},{80.125,0.0514513},{80.159,0.0509871},{80.191,0.0511532},{80.224,0.050925},{80.258,0.0504624},{80.29,0.0504512},{80.324,0.0501152},{80.357,0.0498553},{80.39,0.0497538},{80.423,0.0494939},{80.456,0.0492166},{80.489,0.0490881},{80.522,0.0487998},{80.556,0.0484337},{80.588,0.0485412},{80.622,0.048172},{80.655,0.0478757},{80.687,0.0479769},{80.72,0.0478405},{80.753,0.0475458},{80.786,0.0472717},{80.819,0.0471749},{80.852,0.0470781},{80.885,0.0468198},{80.918,0.046723},{80.951,0.0466072},{80.984,0.0464739},{81.017,0.0461824},{81.049,0.0462868},{81.082,0.0461535},{81.116,0.0456403},{81.149,0.0453772},{81.181,0.0455101},{81.215,0.0450095},{81.248,0.0449063},{81.281,0.0446828},{81.314,0.0446494},{81.348,0.0442232},{81.381,0.0440282},{81.414,0.0438348},{81.446,0.0438742},{81.479,0.0436777},{81.513,0.0434066},{81.546,0.0433716},{81.579,0.0433349},{81.612,0.0432112},{81.645,0.0433043},{81.678,0.043236},{81.71,0.0435573},{81.743,0.0434889},{81.776,0.043438},{81.81,0.0431717},{81.843,0.0431367},{81.875,0.0433281},{81.909,0.0430634},{81.942,0.0430077},{81.975,0.0429378},{82.007,0.0430976},{82.04,0.0430261},{82.073,0.0429562},{82.106,0.0430842},{82.14,0.0428511},{82.173,0.0428477},{82.206,0.0428427},{82.239,0.0429992},{82.271,0.0432413},{82.304,0.0432711},{82.337,0.0434593},{82.37,0.0434891},{82.403,0.0436772},{82.437,0.0433856},{82.47,0.0432508},{82.503,0.0432759},{82.536,0.0431411},{82.569,0.0430063},{82.602,0.0429569},{82.634,0.0430914},{82.668,0.0425955},{82.7,0.0425716},{82.734,0.0422341},{82.767,0.0419932},{82.8,0.041765},{82.833,0.0416967},{82.866,0.0416284},{82.899,0.0414001},{82.933,0.0411782},{82.965,0.0413094},{82.997,0.0414407},{83.03,0.041499},{83.063,0.041399},{83.096,0.0414969},{83.13,0.0413937},{83.163,0.0415185},{83.197,0.0414153},{83.23,0.0413802},{83.262,0.0417521},{83.296,0.0416805},{83.328,0.0420635},{83.362,0.0419919},{83.395,0.0421468},{83.428,0.0422415},{83.462,0.0420671},{83.494,0.0421936},{83.527,0.0422487},{83.56,0.0423039},{83.593,0.0425665},{83.625,0.0429194},{83.659,0.0428161},{83.692,0.0429425},{83.725,0.0430673},{83.758,0.0433726},{83.791,0.0435275},{83.824,0.043684},{83.856,0.044067},{83.889,0.0443834},{83.921,0.0448233},{83.955,0.04469},{83.987,0.045168},{84.02,0.045421},{84.053,0.0456741},{84.086,0.0458385},{84.119,0.0459301},{84.153,0.045792},{84.185,0.0461132},{84.218,0.0463647},{84.251,0.046404},{84.284,0.0465605},{84.317,0.0465555},{84.35,0.046712},{84.383,0.0468669},{84.416,0.0470582},{84.449,0.0474379},{84.482,0.0476577},{84.515,0.0478776},{84.548,0.0480974},{84.581,0.0484771},{84.615,0.0486287},{84.648,0.0488501},{84.681,0.0492314},{84.715,0.049383},{84.748,0.0495854},{84.781,0.0499335},{84.814,0.0502815},{84.848,0.0503967},{84.881,0.0507448},{84.914,0.0509123},{84.947,0.0512287},{84.981,0.0511508},{85.013,0.0517},{85.046,0.0518549},{85.078,0.0523851},{85.111,0.0526698},{85.143,0.0533472},{85.176,0.0536304},{85.21,0.0536807},{85.243,0.0539828},{85.276,0.0542992},{85.309,0.054614},{85.341,0.0551632},{85.374,0.055478},{85.407,0.0558292},{85.44,0.0562089},{85.473,0.0565886},{85.507,0.0565772},{85.539,0.0570282},{85.572,0.0574254},{85.605,0.0576768},{85.638,0.0580882},{85.672,0.05811},{85.705,0.0583615},{85.738,0.058632},{85.771,0.0590734},{85.804,0.059355},{85.838,0.0594084},{85.87,0.0600795},{85.903,0.0606587},{85.936,0.0611667},{85.97,0.0614529},{86.002,0.0621825},{86.036,0.0624687},{86.069,0.0629181},{86.101,0.0635544},{86.134,0.0639641},{86.168,0.0643105},{86.2,0.0649468},{86.233,0.0653581},{86.266,0.0657695},{86.3,0.0661159},{86.333,0.0665272},{86.366,0.0669386},{86.398,0.0677759},{86.432,0.0680289},{86.465,0.0685067},{86.498,0.068983},{86.532,0.0692375},{86.565,0.0696157},{86.598,0.0699289},{86.63,0.0706316},{86.663,0.0711063},{86.696,0.0714195},{86.729,0.0719354},{86.762,0.0723151},{86.796,0.0726298},{86.829,0.0730111},{86.862,0.0735523},{86.895,0.0740729},{86.928,0.0745808},{86.961,0.0750887},{86.994,0.0754368},{87.027,0.0759447},{87.061,0.0761423},{87.093,0.07675},{87.126,0.0771282},{87.158,0.0778974},{87.191,0.0784339},{87.224,0.0788326},{87.257,0.0794038},{87.291,0.079747},{87.324,0.0803183},{87.357,0.0808895},{87.389,0.0819295},{87.422,0.0826306},{87.455,0.0834915},{87.488,0.0841926},{87.521,0.0848937},{87.554,0.0855758},{87.587,0.0862436},{87.62,0.0870713},{87.653,0.0877392},{87.686,0.0885669},{87.719,0.0892347},{87.753,0.0896745},{87.786,0.0905038},{87.819,0.09117},{87.852,0.0919993},{87.885,0.0928255},{87.917,0.0935599},{87.949,0.0941329},{87.983,0.0944111},{88.016,0.0947576},{88.049,0.0950455},{88.082,0.0952954},{88.115,0.0957052},{88.149,0.0958853},{88.181,0.0963648},{88.214,0.0966986},{88.247,0.0970799},{88.28,0.097781},{88.313,0.0981607},{88.346,0.0988618},{88.379,0.0995423},{88.412,0.100368},{88.444,0.101423},{88.477,0.102089},{88.51,0.102915},{88.543,0.103844},{88.576,0.104415},{88.609,0.105308},{88.642,0.106359},{88.674,0.108281},{88.708,0.109545},{88.741,0.111013},{88.774,0.11232},{88.807,0.113467},{88.84,0.115096},{88.873,0.116025},{88.905,0.117152},{88.938,0.118685},{88.971,0.120217},{89.004,0.121268},{89.036,0.122485},{89.069,0.124049},{89.102,0.125133},{89.136,0.125978},{89.169,0.127382},{89.202,0.129104},{89.234,0.131062},{89.267,0.132783},{89.3,0.134823},{89.333,0.136063},{89.367,0.137123},{89.4,0.13862},{89.433,0.140276},{89.466,0.142734},{89.499,0.14407},{89.532,0.145794},{89.565,0.148355},{89.598,0.150275},{89.631,0.152037},{89.665,0.153565},{89.697,0.155611},{89.731,0.157232},{89.763,0.159315},{89.796,0.161167},{89.829,0.163179},{89.862,0.165369},{89.896,0.168621},{89.929,0.170983},{89.962,0.173187},{89.994,0.175938},{90.027,0.178621},{90.06,0.181144},{90.093,0.183669},{90.127,0.186124},{90.16,0.189289},{90.194,0.192127},{90.227,0.197628},{90.259,0.201274},{90.292,0.205174},{90.325,0.209235},{90.358,0.212996},{90.392,0.217023},{90.425,0.224796},{90.457,0.230713},{90.491,0.239061},{90.523,0.246099},{90.556,0.255632},{90.59,0.262701},{90.622,0.274059},{90.655,0.282792},{90.688,0.292805},{90.721,0.305059},{90.753,0.317377},{90.786,0.330112},{90.819,0.341404},{90.852,0.352818},{90.885,0.365167},{90.918,0.378155},{90.951,0.391464},{90.983,0.40884},{91.016,0.422687},{91.048,0.438718},{91.081,0.458206},{91.115,0.481631},{91.148,0.505117},{91.182,0.530002},{91.214,0.564786},{91.247,0.608147},{91.28,0.663512},{91.313,0.7368},{91.347,0.834546},{91.381,0.963205},{91.414,1.12633},{91.446,1.3012},{91.479,1.4384},{91.511,1.48419},{91.545,1.43025},{91.578,1.30693},{91.61,1.15087},{91.643,0.987705},{91.675,0.835225},{91.708,0.700161},{91.742,0.580875},{91.775,0.475575},{91.808,0.388037},{91.842,0.316299},{91.874,0.25654},{91.908,0.205297},{91.941,0.168518},{91.974,0.141022},{92.006,0.12249},{92.04,0.108595},{92.072,0.0868284},{92.106,0.078694},{92.139,0.0727048},{92.172,0.0618365},{92.206,0.0584736},{92.238,0.0531542},{92.27,0.0505546},{92.303,0.0475734},{92.336,0.0452127},{92.369,0.0439602},{92.402,0.0427077},{92.435,0.0411339},{92.469,0.0398195},{92.501,0.0392685},{92.534,0.0383374},{92.568,0.0371813},{92.6,0.0366319},{92.632,0.0346417},{92.665,0.0341507},{92.699,0.0334095},{92.732,0.0328932},{92.765,0.0325367},{92.797,0.0322453},{92.831,0.0313457},{92.865,0.0302863},{92.897,0.0299948},{92.93,0.0294801},{92.963,0.0289653},{92.995,0.0287641},{93.028,0.0282795},{93.062,0.0277266},{93.096,0.026854},{93.129,0.0263709},{93.162,0.0260065},{93.196,0.0252289},{93.229,0.0241996},{93.262,0.0238115},{93.295,0.0235833},{93.327,0.0229452},{93.36,0.0228768},{93.393,0.0226486},{93.426,0.0224204},{93.458,0.022262},{93.491,0.0220512},{93.524,0.0216947},{93.557,0.0213383},{93.589,0.0213714},{93.622,0.0211748},{93.655,0.0209973},{93.688,0.0206741},{93.722,0.0201228},{93.756,0.019733},{93.788,0.0197978},{93.821,0.019492},{93.853,0.0197468},{93.886,0.0196135},{93.919,0.019322},{93.953,0.0186425},{93.986,0.0182069},{94.02,0.0175606}}`

which looks like this plotted:

[image]

How can I fit both peaks at the same time using `NonLinearFit`? And also how can I find the area under the curve for both peaks?

EDIT: I would say that the answer provided by @MarcoB is great and the only thing remaining to ask is if somone knows what equation would be most ideal to better fit both peaks?. I appreciate it in advanced.

EDIT2: I tried using the software origin to try to find what is the best peak for both peaks and it seems that the function BWF is the best for it as written below:

[image: Image 2]

Can someone help me implement this equation with `NonLinearFit`?

Comment: Not everybody here speaks physics. You might want to spell out BWF.

Comment: @JimB BWF stands for "Breit Wigner Fano" Function. This seems to be a good function for both peaks. I appreciate your help as well. I must add here that y0 is just the baseline. And it has 4 parameters: H,Xc,qw and w

Comment: Can you at least tell us the physical origin of these signals?

Comment: Please put that information in your comment into the question.

Comment: @MarcoB the physical original are from a differential scanning calorimetry signal. The x axis is temperature and the yaxis is heat capacity. The peaks represent the melting of two different species in the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pretty much the same code from [my answer to your last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222634/27951):

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
       data,
        height1 Exp[-(x - peakposition1)^2/peakwidth1^2] +
         height2 Exp[-(x - peakposition2)^2/peakwidth2^2] +
          baseline,
        {
          {height1, 0.5}, {peakposition1, 76}, {peakwidth1, 2},
          {height2, 1.3}, {peakposition2, 92}, {peakwidth2, 1},
          {baseline, 0}
        }, x
      ];

fit["BestFitParameters"]

(* Out: {height1 -> 0.364615, peakposition1 -> 75.7626, peakwidth1 -> 0.967389, 
         height2 -> 1.19066,  peakposition2 -> 91.4855, peakwidth2 -> 0.306273, 
         baseline -> 0.0786113}*)

Show[
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All],
  Plot[
    fit[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]},
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All
  ]
]
```

[image]

---

It has to be said, though, that these peaks are obviously non-gaussian. Their fitting will not do you much good apart from perhaps finding their max position (which you could also achieve with [`FindPeaks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html)). For instance, you really should not try to obtain the areas of these peaks from these fits, as they will be quite wrong. You should spend some time trying to figure out which analytical shape your peaks should conform to, from the theory behind your experiment.

---

Here is the same idea, using the Breit-Wigner-Fano line shape you suggested:

```
ClearAll[bwf]
bwf[x_, y0_, h_, xc_, q_, w_] := y0 + h (1 + (x - xc)/(q w))^2 / (1 + ((x - xc)/w)^2)

fitbwf =
  NonlinearModelFit[
    data,
    bwf[x, y0, h1, xc1, q1, w1] + 
      bwf[x, y0, h2, xc2, q2, w2],
    {y0,
     {h1, 0.4}, {xc1, 76}, q1, {w1, 1},
     {h2, 1.2}, {xc2, 91}, q2, {w2, 0.3}
    }, x,
    MaxIterations -> 1000
  ]

Plot[
  fitbwf[x],
  Evaluate@ Flatten@ {x, MinMax[ data[[All,1]] ]},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red,
  Prolog -> {PointSize[0.01], Black, Point[data]}
]
```

I can’t post a picture of the resulting plot above (I’m on mobile), but it’s not that much better than Gaussians. You may have better luck if you manually provide better starting values for the asymmetry parameters `q1` and `q2`.

Comment: MarcoB. Thank you! Yes, I tried the same but the fittings do not look very well and that's the reason I also asked this question. How can I make the fitting better using this code?. Also part of the question is that I am not quite sure what would be the best equation that describe them both to properly do the fitting

Comment: @John As I mentioned at the end, these are not Gaussian-shape peaks (they are asymmetric, they have a left tail, etc). You need to figure out what shape they should be, and then you can use the same approach I use here, but with a different fitting model.

Comment: MarcoB thanks again. Is there any way in Mathematica it can be known what is the best equation that describe both peaks or to find that out?. I was thinking that perhaps there was a way in Mathematica but I do not know.

Comment: Also, could you tell me how to find the area individually for each peak even the gaussian equation you used? Thanks

Comment: @John No, there is no way for Mathematica (or for any other general-purpose fitting software) to make that decision for you. In fact, many peak shapes will probably fit; it is in the eye of the experimenter, with the help of your knowledge of the associated physics, that you can make that decision. For the area, you can use the same techniques from the previous answer, but I **strongly caution you against doing so**, as the answers would be practically meaningless from this fit.

Comment: MarcoB. I used Origin and as you can see in my new edit it seems that the best equation is `BWF` written in the EDIT. Could you please help me implement this equation with your code? I am very very new in Mathematica and I am in the process of learning all this about fitting.

Comment: @John take a look at my last edit

Comment: I'm betting that `NonlinearModelFit` found the "best" fit and better starting values for `q1` and `q2` will not change the results.  I would it stronger in that it's just as bad as the Gaussian fit.

Comment: @JimB and @MarcoB I think both of you are right and perhaps the BWF fit is not better than a gaussian fit. I think at this point I will stay with the the gaussian fit as it is simpler. I know that you advise againts finding the area but I still will need to at least report it. I used `area1 = NIntegrate[fit[x] - baseline /. fit["BestFitParameters"], {x, 66, 80}];
area2 = NIntegrate[fit[x] - baseline /. fit["BestFitParameters"], {x, 85, 95}];` to find the area for each curve but they both seem to be giving the same value (which even with a bad fit is obvisouly wrong). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MarcoB. Could you also post how to find the area even for the gaussian fit in your answer to have at least a more complete answer?. I will acept your answer after that. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I am not a physicist but the need (craving? compulsion?) for the area under a parametric curve when there's such a poor fit makes no sense.

Your data is pretty dense (lots of observations uniformly spaced) so why not pick a reasonable baseline (another concept I don't understand as the left and right side of the peaks seem to have different levels) and then just find the mean of the response variable, subtract the chosen baseline, and finally multiply by the width of the peak?  If you had a good fit, that's essentially what you'd get.

For the left peak:

```
left = Select[data, #[[1]] < 82 &];
baseline = Min[left]
(* 0.0429378 *)
width = Max[left[[All, 1]]] - Min[left[[All, 1]]]
(* 13.946 *)
area = (Mean[left[[All, 2]]] - baseline)*width
(* 1.07861 *)
```

Comment: that is a very good input and you are right! This is a simpler way to find the areas. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using two gaussians one can not reproduce the asymmetry of the Fano peaks. For each peak the Fano formula contains a supplementary asymmetry parameter q. The same input data give:

```
    fitFano = 
NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  baseline + 
   CFF1*(parmFF1 + (z - absc01)/
         gammaF1)^2/(1 + ((z - absc01)/gammaF1)^2) +
   CFF2*(parmFF2 + (z - absc02)/
         gammaF2)^2/(1 + ((z - absc02)/gammaF2)^2), {{baseline, 
    0}, {CFF1, 1}, {parmFF1, 3.}, {gammaF1, 0.1}, {absc01, 75}, {CFF2,
     1}, {parmFF2, 2.}, {gammaF2, 0.25}, {absc02, 90}}, z, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, 
  Method -> {NMinimize, 
    Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 40, 
      "ScalingFactor" -> 0.95, "CrossProbability" -> 0.05, 
      "PostProcess" -> {FindMinimum, Method -> "QuasiNewton"}}}]
    fanoModel = Normal[fitFano]
fitFano["ParameterTable"]
(*   best fitted parameters in the Mathematica format       *)
result \
= fitFano["BestFitParameters"]
(*   numerical values of the fit. Use "/." is a replace all operator. \
Here it selects the numericla value of a parameter *)

baselinefit = baseline /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
CFF1fit = CFF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
parmFF1fit = parmFF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
gammaF1fit = gammaF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
absc01fit = absc01 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
CFF2fit = CFF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
parmFF2fit = parmFF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
gammaF2fit = gammaF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
absc02fit = absc02 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
Print["baselinefit=", baselinefit, ", CFF1fit=", CFF1fit, ", \
parmFF1fit=", parmFF1fit, ", gammaF1fit=", gammaF1fit, ", \
absc01fit=", absc01fit]
Print["             CFF2fit=", CFF2fit, ", parmFF2fit=", parmFF2fit, \
", gammaF2fit=", gammaF2fit, ", absc02fit=", absc02fit]
residuals = Norm[fitFano["FitResiduals"]];
Print["residuals=", residuals]
1.82436 - (1.3415 (-0.181654 - 4.63438 (-91.5646 + z))^2)/(
 1 + 21.4775 (-91.5646 + z)^2) - (
 0.42502 (0.183719 + 1.54695 (-76.0528 + z))^2)/(
 1 + 2.39304 (-76.0528 + z)^2)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, "Obs"}, LabelStyle -> {Directive[20, 20]}], 
 Plot[fitFano[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: two Fano features fit]

Comment: The figure with the fit and data was not created from the code presented.

Comment: On Win7x64-v12.2.0 I see this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFei.png)

Comment: @Syed I see the same plot on 13.0.1.0 WIndows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Using two gaussians one can not reproduce the asymmetry of the Fano peaks. For each peak the Fano formula contains a supplementary asymmetry parameter q. The same input data give:

```
    fitFano = 
NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  baseline + 
   CFF1*(parmFF1 + (z - absc01)/
         gammaF1)^2/(1 + ((z - absc01)/gammaF1)^2) +
   CFF2*(parmFF2 + (z - absc02)/
         gammaF2)^2/(1 + ((z - absc02)/gammaF2)^2), {{baseline, 
    0}, {CFF1, 1}, {parmFF1, 3.}, {gammaF1, 0.1}, {absc01, 75}, {CFF2,
     1}, {parmFF2, 2.}, {gammaF2, 0.25}, {absc02, 90}}, z, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, 
  Method -> {NMinimize, 
    Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 40, 
      "ScalingFactor" -> 0.95, "CrossProbability" -> 0.05, 
      "PostProcess" -> {FindMinimum, Method -> "QuasiNewton"}}}]
    fanoModel = Normal[fitFano]
fitFano["ParameterTable"]
(*   best fitted parameters in the Mathematica format       *)
result \
= fitFano["BestFitParameters"]
(*   numerical values of the fit. Use "/." is a replace all operator. \
Here it selects the numericla value of a parameter *)

baselinefit = baseline /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
CFF1fit = CFF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
parmFF1fit = parmFF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
gammaF1fit = gammaF1 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
absc01fit = absc01 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
CFF2fit = CFF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
parmFF2fit = parmFF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
gammaF2fit = gammaF2 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
absc02fit = absc02 /. fitFano["BestFitParameters"];
Print["baselinefit=", baselinefit, ", CFF1fit=", CFF1fit, ", \
parmFF1fit=", parmFF1fit, ", gammaF1fit=", gammaF1fit, ", \
absc01fit=", absc01fit]
Print["             CFF2fit=", CFF2fit, ", parmFF2fit=", parmFF2fit, \
", gammaF2fit=", gammaF2fit, ", absc02fit=", absc02fit]
residuals = Norm[fitFano["FitResiduals"]];
Print["residuals=", residuals]
1.82436 - (1.3415 (-0.181654 - 4.63438 (-91.5646 + z))^2)/(
 1 + 21.4775 (-91.5646 + z)^2) - (
 0.42502 (0.183719 + 1.54695 (-76.0528 + z))^2)/(
 1 + 2.39304 (-76.0528 + z)^2)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, "Obs"}, LabelStyle -> {Directive[20, 20]}], 
 Plot[fitFano[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell you posted the same answer twice, with a different figure. Please delete the older answer. For future reference, you can always edit your answer using the edit link under it.

Comment: With Mathematica 13.0.1.0 (Windows 10) the code results in a very poor fit.  I believe the fit you got but if you could also show the output from `fitFano["ParameterTable"]`, that would be great.